# Are diagonals of a regular polygon equal?

Tags: geometry

Are the diagonals of a regular polygon always equal in length? If yes then can you please explain me the proof?

Comment: Take the square, for example. The two diagonals are indeed different. They intersect in a right angle. So they are not equal.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde sorry I meant equal length 

Comment: No, you still say "always equal".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you mean to ask whether all diagonals of a regular polygon are of *equal length*. Take a look at this regular hexagon, and decide yourself:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I realised that later but I thought of not deleting the question. (Although the diaonals passing through the centre are equal right? If we take O as centre then ∆AOB, ∆BOC... ∆FOA will be congruent ig)

Comment: In this case, yes, the diagonals passing through the center are equal in length. BUT that doesn't necessarily generalize to other regular polygons, because there may not be diagonals 
"passing through the center"

Comment: Consider a regular heptagon; look at this: https://mathmonks.com/polygon/diagonals-of-a-polygon

Answer (score 1):

No,they aren't.You may consider any regular polygon having greater than 5 sides for example.